# Windows Command line sort

Tags: windows, command-line

I have a requirement where I want to read one file content, sort the content and write the sorted content into the same file. Like sorting the file.

I know less about Windows command. I know Windows sort command will help and but I am not aware of writing into the same file.

Need your expert help guys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

look at the help of sort.exe by typing `sort /?` in the console :

> /O[UTPUT] [drive:][pathname]
>            The file where the sorted input is to be stored.
>            If not specified, the data is written to standard output.
>            Specifying an output file is faster than redirecting
>            standard output to a file.

```
sort sort.txt /o sort.txt
```

or if you want to append the result to another file

```
sort sort.txt >> c:\temp\cominedresult.txt
```

Comment: superb ... quick... Thanks dude